# Overloading function with (un)signed chars, passing char, is it guarnateed not to compile?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code will not compile on my compiler. I understand why.

```
void f(signed char x);
void f(unsigned char x);

int main()
{
    char c = 0;
    f(c);
}
```

`signed char`, `unsigned char` and `char` are three distinct types, and this causes ambiguity in the overloading.

My question is, is this always guaranteed to be ambiguous and therefore a compile error? Is there some rule which optionally permits a compiler to accept this code? Is there some exotic but legal combination of integer sizes that would cause this code to compile?

Comment: Yes. No. No. (15 chars)

Comment: `Is there some exotic but legal combination of integer sizes that would cause this code to compile` .. sure `static_cast<signed char>(c)` isn't exotic and totally legal as is `static_cast<unsigned char>(c)` .. but just because you can, doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: @txtechhelp he means without changing the code

Answer (score 5):

Even worse than your example, all integer conversions are treated equally. For function arguments that are integer expressions to integer parameters, either the type is an exact match or it's not.

```
void f( short ) {}
void f( long ) {}

int main() {
    f( 1000000 ); // Ambiguous, even though one alternative loses numeracy.
}
```

There's no consideration for integer conversion rank in the [over.ics.rank] rules for finding the best argument-parameter match. Even if there were, the three `char` types are required to have the same rank.

---

Even worse than my example, a call may be ambiguous even if the argument couldn't initialize one of the two alternatives at all.

```
void f( short ) {}
void f( long ) {}

int main() {
    f({ 1000000 }); // Ambiguous, even though narrowing to short is prohibited.
}
```

This doesn't seem to be normatively required by the standard, and I'm mulling over filing a defect report. (§13.3.3.1.5/9.1 is ambiguous.)

Comment: `1000000` to `short` is not UB. It's implementation-defined, per [conv.integral]/p3.

Comment: @T.C. Fixed. It's nonsense to be avoided, either way.

Comment: Good answer. I didn't know that adding `{ }` prevents shortening.